# How to remove a consul service endpoint / id?

Tags: consul

If I have registered two "endpoints" for a service like so:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{"ID": "app1", "Name": "app", "Address": "1.2.3.4", "Port": 3000}' http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/service/register
curl -X PUT -d '{"ID": "app2", "Name": "app", "Address": "5.6.7.8", "Port": 3000}' http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/service/register
```

How can I later delete a specific endpoint - for example the second (with ID `app2`?

Reading thruogh https://www.consul.io/api/agent/service.html I can only find a way to delete the entire service

Answer (score 0):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/service/deregister/${ID_GOES_HERE}
```

So in the above example

```
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/service/deregister/app2
```